# upgrade 11 to 12 still boots 11

Tags: upgrade, kernel

I just upgraded my Acer Aspire One from 11 to 12.04, but while the desktop says 12.04, and trying to redo the upgrade says "you're already got 12 installed", the grub menu only has 11.04 options and I get a 2.6 kernel, not a 3.8.  In particular, the atheros driver isn't getting loaded.  Am I going to have to reinstall from scratch?

Comment: try `sudo do-release-upgrade`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is grub was not correctly updated to show the new OS version and kernel. You should not need to re-install.

- Provided that you are using Grub2, open your terminal and enter the following command to update grub:

  sudo update-grub
- It will show a list as it configures the boot order which will look similar to this:

  ```
  Generating grub.cfg ...
  using custom appearance settings
  Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.7.0-7-generic
  Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.7.0-7-generic
  Found Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sda1
  Found Debian GNU/Linux (6.0.7) on /dev/sda4
  Found openSUSE 12.3 (x86_64) on /dev/sdb1
  done
  ```

Once finished reboot your computer, grub should now have the new and correct entries.

Comment: Close, but it gave me the clue: update-grub just rebuilt grub.cfg with what it already had, but for some reason it wasn't using it.  I suspect maybe it was still using grub1?  I did a man -k grub and found grub-setup which reinstalled the grub boot loader, which then used the right files (though I thought it always used /boot/grub/*?).  Anyway, grub-setup did the trick. Thanks!